# How to write Objective-c code in python

Tags: python, objective-c, python-2.7

I want to write equivalent Python code of following Objective-C code using PyObjC. Not sure how to do?  Any help would be highly appreciated on ow to bridge Objective-C code into Python.

```
#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>

...
// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep prevents display sleep,
// kIOPMAssertionTypeNoIdleSleep prevents idle sleep

//reasonForActivity is a descriptive string used by the system whenever it needs 
//  to tell the user why the system is not sleeping. For example, 
//  "Mail Compacting Mailboxes" would be a useful string.

//  NOTE: IOPMAssertionCreateWithName limits the string to 128 characters. 
CFStringRef* reasonForActivity= CFSTR("Describe Activity Type");

IOPMAssertionID assertionID;
IOReturn success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep, 
                                    kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, reasonForActivity, &assertionID); 
if (success == kIOReturnSuccess)
{

    //Add the work you need to do without 
    //  the system sleeping here.

    success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
    //The system will be able to sleep again. 
}
...
```

Comment: This is not Objective C, this is plain C. PyObjC won't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to generate a bridge file for the `IOKit.framework` first using the `gen_bridge_metadata` command.

you can hard code the contents of the file into a Python variable if you want.

then load the bridge into into PyObjC using `objc.parseBridgeSupport()`

```
objc.parseBridgeSupport(BRIDGE_FILE_STRING, globals(), objc.pathForFramework("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework"))`
```

examples [here](http://www.slevenbits.com/blog/2012/11/pyobjc-and-iokit-on-mac-os-x.html) and [here](https://github.com/Kentzo/Power/blob/master/power/darwin.py)

[Here is an example](https://github.com/pudquick/pypmset/blob/master/pypmset.py) that does almost exactly what you are asking.